# Using attr to replace html width tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, attr

I'm using this code below to replace

```
$('iframe').map(function(i, el) {
       var amp_iframe = $('<amp-iframe layout="responsive"></amp-iframe>');
       amp_iframe.attr('width', $(this).attr('width'));
       amp_iframe.attr('sandbox', 'allow-scripts allow-same-origin');
return $(this).replaceWith(amp_iframe);
});
```

The output comes like this:

```
<amp-iframe layout=responsive src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/abcxxxxxx/viewform?embedded=true" width=100% height=750 frameborder=0 sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></amp-iframe>
```

I want to convert `width="100%"` to `width="100"` and remove `%`. How would i go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting `"100%"` from `$(this).attr('width')` then u can use:

```
 $(this).attr('width').replace(/\%/, "")
```

But make sure you're getting value for `$(this).attr('width')` by adding fail-safe code, else it'll break.

**Edit**: yes. you can replace like this:

```
let width = $(this).attr('width').replace(/\%/, "")
amp_iframe.attr('width', width);
```

Comment: No no.. I'm sorry. I didn't say it clearly. Please check the question again; I've edited it.